# CSS Alignmnet of border depends on container width

Tags: html, css, grid, border

When you resize `#wrap` width (just open chrome dev tools) you can see that on some sizes the right border (marked in red circle) gets some gap.

Boys and girls, could you please help me to fix it!

```css
#wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 800px;
  #header {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  #grid {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  span {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 30px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="grid">
    <span>Item</span>
    <span>Item</span>
    <span>Item</span>
    <span>Item</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxBeXK)

Comment: and what are the *some sizes* ?

Comment: Sorry for using joxy, but:
[ok](http://joxi.ru/Vm6zGvztDjVwkm),
[not ok](http://joxi.ru/8AnWQGWUj715er).

The same results on 794px, 786px and etc.

Comment: Doesn't happening to me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDWdV.png. But it seems to be a browser bug, not code bug.

Comment: May be it dependce on monitor